# Is there a reason not to make all classes dataclasses?

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

The [dataclasses module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html) introduced in Python 3.7 allows creating classes with less boilerplate code. Other than that, they appear to be identical to regular classes. As dataclass syntax is far more elegant, I am tempted to make all classes in my project dataclasses, even those not primarily intended for holding data. Is there any potential downside to this?

Comment: What's the upside for you to make classes not primarily intended for holding data dataclasses? Can you include in your question an example of such a class and show us what you gain from making it a dataclass?

Comment: @blhsing As stated in the question, more elegant syntax is the upside.